# Disabling Chrome Autofill Issue in Text Box

Tags: forms, google-chrome, autocomplete, textbox

I'm currently facing an issue with Chrome's autofill feature in text boxes. Despite setting autocomplete="off" and trying various approaches, Chrome continues to suggest and apply values that are unrelated. I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions on overcoming this challenge.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CMTw.png)